# Is it possible to have a single web service call for mulitple portlets in a page?

Tags: liferay-6

I am developing a web page using Liferay 6.2 which contains 3 portlets. But for all three portlets web service request is same. so to avoid multiple web service calls, is it possible to make web service call when user loads on the page and the response can be used in all three portlets?

Answer (score 0):

I thhink I would simply use one of the portlets to call the web service and then spread the response via inter portlet communication.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am thinking about this approach only. But i have one more doubt. I have a requirement where i need to show some text from web service in the header banner of liferay theme. Text will be like some heading and subtitle so i can achieve this as here creating a portlet is not a good option as its just two lines of text.